# JSON Decoding Issues in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to use the open weathermap.org api to return the "main" key in JSON. For some reason I keep getting caught up in my error around "failed to convert". I'm not exactly sure why I am failing to convert the JSON anyone have any ideas? Thank you.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        let url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=10514&appid=#####################"
        getData(from: url)
    }
struct Response: Codable {
        let weather: MyResult
    }
struct MyResult: Codable {
        let main: String
    }
```

Below is the function being called to change access the JSON.

```
private func getData(from url:String) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string:url)!, completionHandler: {
            data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print("Something went wrong")
                return
            }
            // have data
            
            var result: Response?
            do {
                result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
            } catch {
                print("failed to convert")
            }
            guard let json = result else {
                return
            }
            print(json.weather.main)
            }).resume()
    }
```

EDIT: This is what the json pulls up. Am I creating the structs incorrectly? if so how should I do it properly? thank you

```
{"coord":{"lon":-73.73,"lat":41.2},"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":291.67,"feels_like":288.73,"temp_min":290.93,"temp_max":292.59,"pressure":1024,"humidity":72},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":5.7,"deg":130},"clouds":{"all":40},"dt":1594956028,"sys":{"type":1,"id":4403,"country":"US","sunrise":1594892168,"sunset":1594945530},"timezone":-14400,"id":0,"name":"Mount Kisco","cod":200}
```

Comment: check your Response model and compare with json response

Comment: @luffy_064 I  added my JSON example. Am I creating the structs incorrectly? If so, could you show me how I would correctly create them? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the JSON response, the property `weather` is an array:

```
{..., weather: [{...}] }
```

but in your model it expects a `MyResult` type. Change it to expect an array of `[MyResult]`:

```
struct Response: Codable {
   let weather: [MyResult]
}
```